# Any ideas for why two side by side print statements in python would not execute?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a class defined as this:

```
class decider(object):

def __init__(self, brain):
    self.brain = brain
    ##stuff
    ## brain is an object
```

In a class function I have two print statements, right next to each other, like so:

```
def somefunction(self, someParam):
    print "Something First"
    print "Another something: " + self.brain.aVariable + ", " + self.brain.anotherVariable
    # more stuff
    # execution continues as normal
    # the object called in brain exists (ive checked)
```

In another function (in the same class) I call this function.The first print statement is printing, the second one is not. No exceptions are raised and the code just skips that line. No crashes either. I find this pretty bizarre and had not happened to me until now. Is there a reason for why this could possibly be happening?

If it matters, I'm running python 2.7 on an embedded system with an ATOM Z530 processor.

Comment: Have you tried adding `sys.stdout.flush()` below the print statements?

Answer (score 0):

Could be buffered? Does anything print after the second call?

Add another print after the second call to force to clear the buffer

Comment: I added a third print statement and it does not print. Im guessing my funciton is returning None somehow.

Comment: Well, without the full script it's difficult.  But, if you are using the prints for debugging, I urge you to check the logging module. In the long term is better.